# trying to overload [] to traverse doubley linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been scratching my head all day trying to figure this out, because as far as I can see I already have the code written in my overloaded + and - operators, i need to figure out how to overload the [] operators so that when a value is placed inside of them it will traverso the list correctly and point to the info, ex..[5] would move it iter forward 5, [-5] would move it backward, any help would be greatly appreciated, like I said, it seems as if I should almost have the code written already in my + and -...

```
typename doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator+(const int amount) const {
    doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator tempClone(*this);
    tempClone.pastBoundary=false;
    T i;

    if(amount < 0)
    {
    return this->operator-(-amount);
    }

    for(i=0; i < amount; i++)
    {   
    if(tempClone.current->forward == NULL)
    {
       tempClone.pastBoundary =true;
    }else
    {
       ++tempClone;
    }
    }
    if(tempClone.pastBoundary == true)
    {
    return *this;
    }else
    {
        return tempClone;   
    }
    }

template <typename T>
typename doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator-(const int amount) const {
    doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator tempClone(*this);
    tempClone.pastBoundary=false;
    T i;

    if(amount < 0)
    {
    return this->operator+(-amount);
    }

    for(i=0; i < amount; i++)
    {   
        if(tempClone.current->backward == NULL)
    {
       tempClone.pastBoundary =true;
    }else
    {
       --tempClone;
    }
    }

    if(tempClone.pastBoundary == true)
    {
    return *this;
    }else
    {
        return tempClone;   
    }
}


template <typename T>
T& doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator[](const int index) {
doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator tempClone(*this);

if(index >= 0){
   return this->operator+(index);
 }else{
   return this->operator-(index);
 }
```

Comment: Couldn't you just call your overloaded + and - operators within operator[]?

Comment: You want to use the operator in a non-intended way. Apart from that you'll need to define an anchor, in order to traverse relatively from it. Are you using a container from STL? Because you shouldn't reinvent the wheel...

Comment: thats what i assumed but I error our when I try to call them inside the [], which is why i am so confused, because all the pieces i think are there.

Comment: As a sidenote, `[]` on a list may not be the best idea. You may get too comfortable and use it a lot with no regards to performance.

Comment: You'd want to call `operator-(-index)` surely? What error are you getting?

Comment: If you experience strange errors, you should include all relevant information about these errors. "I can't do X, help" is not constructive. "I tried X by means of Y, but got an error Z at line N" is much better.

Comment: does this compile? i guess the return values should be "T", and not "typename"

Comment: My apologies, it would make sense to see the error, and this is it.                                                                 'return' : cannot convert from 'doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator' to 'int &'

Comment: Deamonpg I see what you are saying, it isnt typname and is T.  there may lie my problem in my thinking.

Answer (score 5):

Your `operator+` returns an iterator, so `operator[]` should indirect the return value:

```
template <typename T>
T& doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator[](const int index) {
  return *(this + index);
}
```

As mentioned elsewhere, it's misleading to provide `operator+` or `operator[]` for a non-random-access container, as the O(n) performance may be surprising.

Comment: the indirect value is where I was getting wrapped up, the overloaded + does return an iterator and I was stuck on only thinking about returning it.  perfect way of explaining where I was going off coarse and I appreciate it.

Comment: I just dont believe the return is returning the right value the T is looking for, I need to figure out how to cast it to what it wants.

Comment: @tattoo3d that'll depend on how you've written `operator*`.